# write each block of text between two markers to a file with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I would like to extract each block of text between the `START` and `END` markers to a separate file. Sed would be the preferred tool but grep and awk would also be ok.

Given the following file contents:

```
abc
START
  def
END
ghi
START
  jkl
END
mno
```

sed should create two files respectively with the contents:

```
START
  def
END
```

and

```
START
  jkl
END
```

I know how to get the contents between two regular expressions with sed:

```
sed -n '/START/,/END/p'
```

There is also this option to execute shell commands within sed when supplying the `e` flag. Can this be leveraged for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/START/,/END/!d' file | csplit -z - '/END/1' '{*}'
```

Use sed to gather up all lines between start and end separators, then apply csplit to create separate files for each group of lines.

Comment: ++ ve for nice code. Thank you for very nice code, could you please little explain about csplit will be grateful to you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 csplit is a variant on split. It takes a file and some patterns (with an offset if necessary). See info/man csplit or csplit -h.

Comment: Nice approach but why does it generate 3 files for the example? The last one is empty and the first two are as expected.

Comment: @PeterLutz Ooops! Forgot the `-z` option in csplit to prevent empty files!

Answer (score 1):

awk to save here:

```
awk '/END/{flag="";print > i"_file";close(i"_file");next} /START/{flag=1;print > ++i"_file";next} flag{print > i"_file"}'  Input_file
```

Output it will create 2 files named 1_file and 2_file with following contents.

```
cat 1_file
START
  def
END

cat 2_file
START
  jkl
END
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/END/{
  flag="";
  print > i"_file";
  close(i"_file");
  next
}
/START/{
  flag=1;
  print > ++i"_file";
  next
}
flag{
  print > i"_file"
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting csplit

Thanks potong

So without sed

```
csplit -z --suppress-matched infile %START%-1 /END/1 {*}
```

-m = --suppress-matched don't work.

manpage fr tell -m but it's wrong.

Comment: Works with the example, but if `START` is on first line it complains that line number is out of range

Comment: You can use it like that (echo;cat infile) | csplit - -z -s --suppress-matched %START%-1 /END/1 {*}